# How to trace a radio button change?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to delete attribute "disabled" in my input area or if I choose another radio button, will add "disabled" in my input. This code doesn't right work:

```js
var radio_3 = document.getElementById("Radio3");
var input_long = document.getElementById("inputLong");

radio_3.addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (radio_3.checked) {
    input_long.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    input_long.setAttribute("disabled");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="inputLong">Предпочтительная для Вас длительность конференции?</label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio1">1 день</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio2" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio2">2 дня</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio3" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio3">Другое</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mt-1" id="inputLong" placeholder="" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the event handler to each button 
and I choose to use .disabled instead of setAttribute which works poorly with disabled. I removed the attribute from the input field and set it in code

NOTE: This code also will set the disabled depending on which button is checked
at load time

```js
var rads = document.querySelectorAll("[name=how_long]");
for (var i=0;i<rads.length;i++) {
   rads[i].onclick=function() {
     document.getElementById("inputLong").disabled=this.id!="Radio3";
  }
}  
document.getElementById("inputLong").disabled=!document.getElementById("Radio3").checked;
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="inputLong">Предпочтительная для Вас длительность конференции?</label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio1">1 день</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio2" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio2">2 дня</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio3" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio3">Другое</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mt-1" id="inputLong" placeholder="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `change` listener is only on `radio_1` (or, the `#radio_3` `input`) - the listener runs when the radio button is selected, but *not* when some *other* radio button is selected. Add a listener to *each* radio button instead:

```js
var input_long = document.getElementById("inputLong");

const listener = (e) => {
  input_long.disabled = e.target.id === 'Radio3'
  ? false
  : true;
};

document.querySelectorAll('input[name="how_long"]').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("change", listener);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="inputLong">Предпочтительная для Вас длительность конференции?</label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio1">1 день</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio2" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio2">2 дня</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio3" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio3">Другое</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mt-1" id="inputLong" placeholder="" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The change event doesn't trigger when you click on radio 1 and 2. So you would need to register event handlers separately for them.

In the snippet below, I have declared the event handler separately, and bound it to the radio buttons through separate calls to `addEventListener`.

```js
var radio_1 = document.getElementById("Radio1");
var radio_2 = document.getElementById("Radio2");
var radio_3 = document.getElementById("Radio3");
var input_long = document.getElementById("inputLong");

var eventHandler = function() {
  if (radio_3.checked) {
    input_long.removeAttribute("disabled");
  } else {
    input_long.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  }
};

radio_1.addEventListener("change", eventHandler);
radio_2.addEventListener("change", eventHandler);
radio_3.addEventListener("change", eventHandler);
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <label for="inputLong">Предпочтительная для Вас длительность конференции?</label>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio1">1 день</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio2" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio2">2 дня</label>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="Radio3" name="how_long" class="custom-control-input">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="Radio3">Другое</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mt-1" id="inputLong" placeholder="" disabled>
</div>
```

---

There are ways to simplify the event registration part, such as listening for events on a containing element, and react accordingly. But I have tried to keep it simpler in the snippet above. You can read the following question about event bubbling if you're interested in such an approach: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing#4616720)